# How to use formatting log messages (get time_t, timeval, errno)?

Tags: ios, swift, logging

How to use System log? I go through this apple document:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging

But can't get the formatting log messages.

Using this code:

> os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Time: %{time_t}d", time_t)

OS_LOG_DEFAULT shows an error:

[image]

How to use this OS_LOG_DEFAULT, how to get a all formatting log messages?

```
(time_t,timeval,timespec,errno,iec-bytes,bitrate,iec-bitrate,uuid_t)
```

Want to know how to use this performing logging:

```
os_log("This is a log message.")

os_log("This is additional info that may be helpful for troubleshooting.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)

let customLog = OSLog(subsystem: "com.your_company.your_subsystem_name.plist", category: "your_category_name")
os_log("This is info that may be helpful during development or debugging.", log: customLog, type: .debug)
```

How to use this in my application, want to get formatting log messages, performing logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're having problems accessing `OS_LOG_DEFAULT` from swift. `OS_LOG_DEFAULT` is an Objective-C macro which you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_log_default).

To use this in swift, do the following using `OSLogType.default`:

```swift
import os

os_log(OSLogType.default, "Message")
```